# What is the use of PlaceholderFragment Segement

Tags: android, admob

I'm following the quick start guide on how to add Admob ad to Android [Admob Quick start for Android](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start)

I saw on the layout XML file the are 2 Segment as shown below:

```
<fragment android:name="com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adFragment" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/adFragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.example.bannerexample.MainActivity$AdFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

when I integrated this to my application. The were run time error where it says it couldn't inflate the layout XML file. However, when I removed the the first Segment "MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" everything works fine.
Hence, is there any problem if I removed the first segment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment` is just a fragment inside `MainActivity` to show that it is going to be displayed there on the screen. This is just an example. You can modify according to your needs.

You getting that error probably because your `MainActivity` doesn't have any fragment called `PlaceholderFragment`.

There is absolutely no problem in deleting that. Its just that no fragment will be displayed as a placeholder